# scatter plot against all groups for a long data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I am pretty sure something like this is already asked but I don't know how to search for it.

I often get data in a wide format like in my little example with 3 experiments (a-c). I normally convert to long format and convert the values by some function (here `log2` as an example).

What I often want to do is to plot all experiments against each other and here I am looking for a handy solution. How can I convert my data frame to get facets for example with `a~b`, `a~c` and `b~c`...

So far I `tidy::spread` the data again and execute 3 times a `ggplot` command with the individual column names as `x` and `y`. Later I merge the individual graphs together.

Is there a more convenient way?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  names=letters,
  a=1:26,
  b=1:13,
  c=11:36
)

df %>%
  tidyr::gather(experiment, value, -names) %>%
  mutate(log2.value=log2(value))
```

**EDIT**
Since I got a very useful answer from @hdkrgr I adapted a bit my code. The `inner_join` was a great trick which I can implement to automate my idea, what I still miss is a clever filter to get rid of the redundant data, since I don't want to plot `c~c` or `b~a` if I already plot `a~b`.
I solved this now by providing the pairings I want to do, but can anyone think ob a straight forward solution? I couldn't think of something which gives me the unique pairing.

```
my_pairs <- c('a vs. b', 'a vs. c', 'b vs. c')

df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  tidyr::gather(experiment, value, -names) %>%
  mutate(log2.value=log2(value))  %>%
  inner_join(., ., by=c("names")) %>%
  mutate(pairing=sprintf('%s vs. %s', experiment.x, experiment.y)) %>%
  filter(pairing %in% my_pairs) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(log2.value.x, log2.value.y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ pairing, labeller=label_both)
```

Comment: have a look at `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` in ggplot. These usually work best when the data is in long format.

Comment: I am aware of those functions, but do not see how to use them since `x` and `y` are in the same column. Could you post an example how you would to this with my mutated long data frame?

Comment: ah... I think I only now understood what you really want to do. I'll post an answer, although it's slightly more complicated than I i'd like...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way starting from long format would be to do a self-join on the long-data in order to get all combinations of two experiments in each row:

```
df %>%
    tidyr::gather(experiment, value, -names) %>%
    mutate(log2.value=log2(value)) %>%
    inner_join(., ., by=c("names")) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(log2.value.x, log2.value.y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(experiment.y ~ experiment.x)
```

[image]

Edit: To avoid plotting redundant experiment-pairs, you can do:

```
df %>%
    tidyr::gather(experiment, value, -names) %>%
    mutate(log2.value=log2(value)) %>% inner_join(., ., by=c("names")) %>% 
    filter(experiment.x < experiment.y) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(log2.value.x, log2.value.y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~experiment.y + experiment.x)
```

[image]

Comment: Great idea with this inner join. this almost solved my problem (updated my answer). I do a `facet_wrap` and filter the redundant plots manually but would love to filter them out automatically. Removing `a vs a` is easy, but `b vs a` and not `a vs b` is not as easy. Any idea?

Comment: Do lexicographical comparison? `... %>% filter(experiment.x < experiment.y) %>% ...`
Edit: tried it and it works. In that case `facet_wrap` ends up being much easier to grasp than `facet_grid`

Comment: This is awesome easy!!! Have to check if this works in my real world data but it should... will get back to you!

Answer (score 3):

This is really interesting because it's actually more complex than it first seems. One thing that sticks out is getting *unique* pairs of experiments—it seems like you'd want a vs b but not necessarily b vs a as well. To do that, you need the unique set of experiment pairs.

Initially, I tried to work from your `gather`ed data, but realized it might be simpler to start from the wide version. Take the names of the experiments from the column names—you can do this multiple ways, but I just took the strings that aren't `"names"`—and get the combinations of them. I pasted them together to make them a little easier to work with.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  names=letters,
  a=1:26,
  b=1:13,
  c=11:36
) %>%
  as_tibble()

exp <- stringr::str_subset(names(df), "names", negate = T)

pairs <- combn(exp, 2, paste, simplify = F, collapse = ",") %>%
  unlist()
pairs
#> [1] "a,b" "a,c" "b,c"
```

Then, for each pair, extract the associated column names, do a little tidyeval to select those columns, do the `log2` transform that you had. I had to detour here to rename the columns with something I could refer back to—I think this isn't necessary, but I couldn't get my tidyeval working inside the `ggplot` `aes`. Someone else might have an idea on that. Then make your plot, and label the axes and title accordingly. That leaves you with a list of 3 plots.

```r
plots <- purrr::map(pairs, function(pair) {
  cols <- strsplit(pair, split = ",", fixed = T)[[1]]
  df %>%
    select(names, !!cols[1], !!cols[2]) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-names), log2) %>%
    rename(exp1 = !!cols[1], exp2 = !!cols[2]) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = exp1, y = exp2)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = cols[1], y = cols[2], title = pair)
})
```

Use your method of choice to put the plots together however you want. I went with `cowplot`, but I also like the `patchwork` package.

```r
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plots, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I did something similar before but I was wondering if there isn't a straight forward solution with less code. Somehow the `filter` function by @hdkrgr works fine for me now, didn't saw a problem and it is basically one simple filter

Comment: @drmariod that's totally fair, I don't know why I'm always scared of the self-join but it's definitely a good way to go in this case

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not what you want, but if the purpose is to explore the correlation pattern between each variable, you may want to consider `ggpairs` from the `GGally` package. It provides not only scatter plots, but also correlation score and distribution.

```
library(GGally)

ggpairs(df[, c("a", "b", "c")])
```

[image]

Comment: I was aware of `GGally` but I don't want to create so many facets because most of them show redundant information or I don't need them. Or is the a way to just return the lower diagonal of this plot as individual facets?

Answer (score 1):

You could start from creating all combinations via `combn`and then work your way through:

```
library(purrr)

t(combn(names(df)[-1], 2)) %>% ## get all combinations  
   as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
   mutate(l = paste(V1, V2, sep = " vs. ")) %>%
   pmap_dfr(function(V1, V2, l) 
     df %>% 
       select(one_of(c(V1, V2))) %>% ## select the elements given by the combination
       mutate_all(log2) %>%
       setNames(c("x", "y")) %>%
       mutate(experiment = l)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~experiment)
```

[image: Scatterplot]